# Create Measure to Calculate Value Based on Lookup By Date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure that would give me a value based on an expected percentage of of the whole, by date.  This will let me create a  visual showing expected and actual execution values.  I have the actual value calculation down, but I am having issues with the expected calculation.

The table with the expected percentage by date is setup with columns

```
Date, Project, Expected Pct Complete
1/1/2019, ProjA, .20
1/2/2019, ProjA, .40
1/3/2019, ProjA, .60
1/4/2019, ProjA, .80
1/5/2019, ProjA, 1.00
1/1/2019, ProjA, .33
1/2/2019, ProjA, .66
1/3/2019, ProjA, 1.00
```

I then have a table with all the test executions, where the data has this general format,

```
Execution Date, Project, Script, Status
1/1/2019, ProjA, Script1, Passed 
1/1/2019, ProjB, ScriptA, Failed
1/1/2019, ProjA, Script2, Failed
1/2/2019, ProjA, Script3, Passed
```

I want the measure to generate values of form (assume project A & B both have 100 scripts)

```
Date, Expected Amount, Project
1/1/2019, 20, ProjA
1/1/2019, 33, ProjB
1/2,2019, 40, ProjA
1/2/2019, 66, ProjB
1/3/2019, 60, ProjA
1/3/2019, 100, ProjB
1/4/2019, 80, ProjA
1/5/2019, 100, ProjA
```

How can I create this measure so that I can put it into a visualization that will show me that actual vs expected rates, when I select the particular project from a slicer?

Comment: Did you mean to have some `ProjB` rows in the first table?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a calculated column to the first table in your post with the following code.

```
Expected Amount = 
    var _totalScriptsPerProject = 
        CALCULATE ( 
            DISTINCTCOUNT ( tests[Script] ) ; 
            FILTER ( ALL ( tests ) ; tests[Project] = expectations[Project] )
        )
RETURN
    expectations[Expected pct Complete] * _totalScriptsPerProject
```

(note I assumed the first table to be called 'expectations' and the second 'tests', also note I use semicolons as argument seprator)